# How to use if function within an else function

Tags: php, javascript, preg-match

Im trying to use an `if` function within the `else` function of a `preg_match` command.

`$month1data` is fetched from CURL and has been checked to work.

The following code is:

```
global $attempt;
$attempt = mysql_escape_string($_GET['attempt']);

if (preg_match('/<td colspan=8(.*)<\/table/s', $month1data, $matches)) {
    //Content found do stuff here

    unset ($ch);
    unset ($cache);
    unset ($firstmonthdata);
    unset ($matches);
} else { // start else preg match
    if ($attempt = '3') { //start if attempt = 3

        echo 'failed 3 times - showing error';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        window.location = "http://www.website.com/error.php?error=2"
        //-->
        </script>';

    } // end if attempt = 3
    else { //start if attempt dont = 3

        echo 'keep trying for 3 times';
        $attempt = $attempt +1;
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        window.location = "http://www.website.com/page.php?email=' . $email . '&password=' . $password . '&attempt=' . $attempt . '"
        //-->
        </script>';
    }// end if attempt dont 3 else
} // end else preg match
```

However whenever the page is loaded it directs straight to the error page:

```
"http://www.website.com/error.php?error=2"
```

I have looked at several others posts but can't see what's wrong, is it possible to implement these methods in this way or is there just something missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
if ($attempt === '3') {
             ^^^
```

You are assigning `3` to `$attempt`.

Or even better as there seems no database involved:

```
$attempt = (int) $_GET['attempt'];

...

if ($attempt === 3) {
```

**Edit:** Apart from that you would be better off using a session for this kind of attempt checking as the visitor can easily manipulate the query string.

Comment: Thank-you, I can't believe I missed this, shows why you shouldn't overlook the simple things!

Comment: @Jack, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13783985/1592648 for a tip on how to avoid mistakes like this in the future. =o)

Answer (score 2):

The following

```
if ($attempt = '3')
```

Should be

```
if ($attempt == '3')
```

Comment: Thank-you, I can't believe I missed this, shows why you shouldn't overlook the simple things!

Comment: Don't forget to mark one of the answers as the correct answer, :)