# using PHP sessions to verify username

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

I fell like this is a pretty simple fix, but i have tried so many different ways of doing this and have spent sooo many hours on google. basically a user logs in and my script makes sure that they are in my database. that works great, then i start my seesion.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['log']=$username;
header("location:lindex.php");
```

On my next page, lindex.php, i call the session into order and try to set an if statement based on whether that value in `$_SESSION['log']` is "support" or not, however it seems that no matter what the value in my session call is, it always performs the if statment  i have tried basing it on string length, strstr, strpos, =="support. nothing is working. any ideas? here is lindex.php:

```
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['log'])){
echo "You must log in";
exit();}

if(strstr($_SESSION['log'], 'support'))
{
header("location:../sindex.php");
}
```

on a side note. if session is empty, it does exit script.

Comment: Why use `log` to key your `username`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(strstr($_SESSION['log'], 'support'))
```

should be:

```
if($_SESSION['log'] == 'support'))
```

Comment: I can't even tell you how many times i have tried that.... and it worked this time. is there a significance between single qoute and double?

Comment: @PhpProg, double quotes would have PHP search for variables within the string, single will not, but should make no difference in this case. You may have accidentally put a single `=` sign so it became `if($_SESSION['log'] = 'support')` which would always be TRUE. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13783985/1592648) for a simple method to avoid such mistakes in the future. =o)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['log'] === "support")) 
{
echo "You are logged in ";
} else {

echo "You are not logged in ";
header("Location: http://site.com/login.php"); //should be always absolute URI
die();
}
```

Comment: What does `if(isset($_SESSION['log'] === "support")) ` do?