# Using PHP sessions to change change html menu items

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a session once a user logs in so that the 'log in' menu item changes to 'log out' for the duration they are logged in. Once logged in, my success.php file runs which is just

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
?>
```

Now under the menu I have

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['loggedin']=1)
echo '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
else
echo '<a href="login.html">Login</a>';
?>
```

I also have a logout page which is just

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
?>
```

What's happening here though is that by default, the logout option is showing rather than log in even though the user hasn't yet logged in to create the session.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way of handling this, but some advice is very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not too sure why this has received so many down votes...

Comment: Up-voted for you, I don't see why it was either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For login:

```
if username and password is ok {

session_start();
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = "something";

}
```

For the menu

```
  if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    echo "<a href="logout.php"> logout </a>";
    } else {

    echo "<a href="login.php"> login </a>";
    }
```

Ok, in order for the session to be remembered as you change pages, you should create a file called `session.php` and store following code.

```
<?php 

    session_start();

     if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && !empty($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {

     return true;
     }else {
     return false;
     }
     }

 ?>
```

Now, include this page in every one of your .php pages

Comment: This seems to have partly done the trick. The default is no longer Logout, but Login like it should be since no session had been set. What seems to be happening now though is that the session isn't being remembered. As soon as I click away from the logged in page, the option changes back to login rather than log out.

Comment: @MichaelN Now, I have included a session setter script, include it in your php files including in your `logout.php` page, and once you include make sure to destroy it.

Comment: @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie Your latest edit is wrong, actually all the code blocks are wrong. =o\

Comment: @MichaelN alll you had to do was make sure to add `session_start();` at the top of each page. The whole `return true` and `return false` code is wrong though. See [return](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) to see why it is incorrectly used above.

Comment: @crypticツ Oh wow, no kidding. Well, problem solved and lesson learned here.

Answer (score 2):

```
if($_SESSION['loggedin']=1)
```

should be:

```
if($_SESSION['loggedin']===1)
```

Comment: As a side note, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13783985/1592648) is a simple trick that can be used to prevent such accidental mistakes in the future.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind. I'm still a little new to this site.

Answer (score 0):

For menu You can Do like this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_email']))
            {
            print "<span class=\"userg1\"><strong>".$user."</strong></span>&nbsp";
            print "<form method=\"link\" action=\"logout.php\">
            <input type=\"submit\" name=\"Log Out\" value=\"Log Out\" class=\"f1\"/>&nbsp;
            </form>";
            }
            else
            {
            print "<form method=\"link\" action=\"formvu.php\">
            <input type=\"submit\" name=\"log In\" value=\"Register\" class=\"f1\"/>&nbsp;
            </form><form method=\"link\" action=\"login2.php\">
                <input type=\"submit\" name=\"log In\" value=\"Log In\" class=\"f1\"/>&nbsp;
                </form>";
            }
```

But do check session before loading full page in very start of page