# Need help incorporating PHP function into simple html

Tags: php, html

I have been able to implement what was shown here: [Using PHP sessions to change change html menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310282/using-php-sessions-to-change-change-html-menu-items/25263438#25263438)

However, I have problems for the pages on my site which are html.  How could I incorporate a php menu like the one above into my simple html pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If by html pages you mean they have .html extensions, you can't.  They need to be PHP pages, (ie. .php extensions) to be able to have PHP code in them.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `php` functions only on `.php` pages. you can't call `server-side` methods on simple `html`

Answer (score 0):

By rule, the php file must have a .php extention. Just as the jpeg file can't have the .png extension or the pepsi can't be in a coke can. ;-)

If you simply change your existing .html files to be a .php file (open and save as with the .php extention) you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.  Is there any advantage disadvantage to having all pages as .php?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the server you can set it to treat files with the .html extension as PHP, in apache you would modify the config like this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
```

Alternatively you could change the extension of your HTML files to .php, however this would require you to update all of your links.