# Simple PHP If / ElseIf statement not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a really simple if / elseif statement that is not working how I want it to...

```
        if ( $title == 'New York' )
        {
        echo 'This is New York';
        }
        elseif ( $title == 'California' )
        {
        echo 'This Is California';
        }
        else if ($title = "Chicago" )
        {
        echo 'This is Chicago';
        }
        else if ($title = "Seattle" )
        {
        echo 'This is Seattle';
        }
        else
        {
        echo 'No Match Found';
        }
```

If $title is set as New York or California then the script works, but if it is set as Chicago, Seattle or something else then it just displays 'This Is California'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should `elseif` be `else if` or vice versa?

Comment: Please read your code more closely. `$title = 'Chicago'` (and others) should almost undoubtedly be `$title == 'Chicago'` (or even better yet, `$title === 'Chicago'`).

Comment: use `==` all the time for comparison instead of `=`.

Comment: Is it normal that you sometimes write 'elseif' and sometimes 'else if' and also sometimes using '"' or ''' to check a string?


' => is for only words
" => checks also for variables

Comment: you should check for equality with == but in your case you do it only first two times , also trim the values and DEBUG!

Comment: I will recommend to use `switch` : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php (more readable in your case)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `=` instead of `==` for the last cases.

This will always be true since this is an assignation.

Replace those by `==` and you're good to go.

Comment: Perfect, always the obvious :)

Answer (score 9):

Careful with `=` and `==`. I think that is the problem.

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13783985/1592648) for a simple method to stop this from happening again even by accident.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( $title == 'New York' )
        {
        echo 'This is New York';
        }
        elseif ( $title == 'California' )
        {
        echo 'This Is California';
        }
        else if ($title == "Chicago" )
        {
        echo 'This is Chicago';
        }
        else if ($title == "Seattle" )
        {
        echo 'This is Seattle';
        }
        else
        {
        echo 'No Match Found';
        }
```

you have to be careful for `==` because `=` will not work properly in if condition for comparison every time

use == for string and === if numeric

Comment: You should probably explain what is wrong instead of just posting code.

Comment: sorry for not explaining i was editing my answer i just entered it by mistake.

Comment: "*`=` will not work in if condition*" actually `=` works perfectly fine in `if()` conditions as it is allowed. Also `==` is not only for string and `===` is not only for numeric, they work for any type of comparison. The latter just does a strict comparison. -1

Comment: ok than try this 

if(1 = 1)
{
echo 'hi';
}

Comment: You are assigning a constant to a constant, which you can't do *anywhere*. why don't you try this: `if ($x = 'yes'){echo $x;}`

Comment: i written this for the best comparison not for that it is strict or something btw thx for information

Comment: what you writing will go into if whatever the condition is true or not

Comment: You need to read the PHP manual particularly this [page](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) and this [page](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) so you can get a better understanding on why your answers explanation is misleading and incorrect. Regardless, I'm not going to argue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `=`. You must use `==` ([PHP operators comparison](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php))

Like below:

```
else if ( $title == "Chicago" )
{
   echo 'This is Chicago';
}
else if ( $title == "Seattle" )
{
   echo 'This is Seattle';
}
else
{
   echo 'No Match Found';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you code example, 'Chicago' and 'Seattle' are being assigned rather compared. "=" vs "=="

For code like this, I would recommend that you checkout the `switch` statement.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if ( $title == 'New York' )
{
   echo 'This is New York';
}
elseif ( $title == 'California' )
{
   echo 'This Is California';
}
elseif ($title == "Chicago" )
{
   echo 'This is Chicago';
}
elseif ($title == "Seattle" )
{
   echo 'This is Seattle';
}
else
{
   echo 'No Match Found';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace = with ==

```
    if ( $title == 'New York' )
    {
      echo 'This is New York';
    }
    else if ( $title == 'California' )
    {
      echo 'This Is California';
    }
    else if ($title == "Chicago" )
    {
      echo 'This is Chicago';
    }
    else if ($title == "Seattle" )
    {
      echo 'This is Seattle';
    }
    else
    {
     echo 'No Match Found';
    }
```

Its working